# using google domains when hosting static site on aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, static-site, google-domain-api

I've set up many static sites on AWS/S3 with other domain registrars; however, google domains is giving me some issues.
**Steps I've taken:**
-on S3/AWS:

1. created bucket domainname.org
2. enabled static website hosting by adding index.html
3. uploaded index.html and related documents to bucket
4. create bucket www.domainname.org to redirect to bucket domainname.org
5. created bucket policy for domainname.org as follows:

   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "AddPerm",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*",
               "Action": [
                   "s3:GetObject"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:s3:::domainname.org/*"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }

on google domains side

1. Created CNAME record with name www and data entry equal to the bucket's endpoint "rightsrequest.org.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
2. Set TTL to 60 so I can see changes.

I can see the site at that endpoint but it is not redirecting/mapping to the domainmae.org as expected. Usually, this set-up would be enough with other registrars

What am I missing? How do you properly set up static site hosting on S3/AWS while using google domains ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Just add a CNAME record pointing to **s3.amazonaws.com.** (yes, the dot included) ... like this:

[image]